# How create a button by programmatically for a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, button

I'm triying to create a GridLayout by programmatically in Kotlin. My code for the XML is this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#46FF4433"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="5">
        app:columnCount="3"
     </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to set 15 buttons into my Grid. My mainActivity is this:

```
    val gridLayout: GridLayout = findViewById(R.id.grid)

    for (i in 1..10){
        val button = Button(this)
        button.text = "Boton: " + i
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        gridLayout.addView(button)

    }
```

But I need each button be like this:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"

        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"

        android:text="Button 1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
    />
```

I think it has something to do with the layout param but I don't know how to set those atributes.

Comment: use Grid Adapter and retrun its size 15 than set the button text into adapter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GridLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams) and [GridLayout.Spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec). You can do something like the following:

```
val button = Button(this)
val lp = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
lp.setGravity(Gravity.FILL)

// GridLayout.spec is immutable, so one can be applied more than once.
// There are several other versions of GridLayout.spec which may be applicable.
lp.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, 1.0f) // row start, weight
lp.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(col, 1.0f) // column start, weight
button.layoutParams = lp
```

I haven't tested this, but it should get your started.